# How to have each dom respond to mouseenter() separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

So I added .each() after seeing that all components were affected by the mouseenter(), but because this is a gallery... I only want one component to be affected..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".component").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(".primary").css({"margin-right":"0", "transition":"1s"});
            $(".secondary").css({"margin-left":"0", "transition":"1s"});
        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(".primary").css({"margin-right":"30px", "transition":"1s"});
            $(".secondary").css({"margin-left":"30px", "transition":"1s"});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: For more INFO, here is the codepen...
http://codepen.io/gebrutommy/pen/GjNjRk?editors=0010

Comment: On mouse event you are then targeting every .primary, try something like $(this).find('.primary')

Answer (score 2):

Use `.children()` or `.find()`

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".component").each(function() {

    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).children(".primary").css({
        "margin-right": "0",
        "transition": "1s"
      });
      $(this).children(".secondary").css({
        "margin-left": "0",
        "transition": "1s"
      });
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).children(".primary").css({
        "margin-right": "30px",
        "transition": "1s"
      });
      $(this).children(".secondary").css({
        "margin-left": "30px",
        "transition": "1s"
      });
    });

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
body {
  background: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.component {} .primary {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.secondary {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container flex row wrap">

  <div class="component flex column">
    <div class="primary"></div>
    <div class="secondary"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="component flex column">
    <div class="primary"></div>
    <div class="secondary"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="component flex column">
    <div class="primary"></div>
    <div class="secondary"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="component flex column">
    <div class="primary"></div>
    <div class="secondary"></div>
  </div>

</div>
<!--container-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Use event propagation mechanism in javascript

```
var theParent = document.querySelector("#idOfParent");
theParent.addEventListener("mouseenter", doYourStuffforMouseEnterEvent,false);
theParent.addEventListener("mouseleave", doYourStuffforMouseLeaveEvent,false);

function doYourStuffforMouseEnterEvent(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
     var Item = e.target.id;
     alert("This item is the current hover item " + Item );
     $(".primary").css({"margin-right":"0", "transition":"1s"});
     $(".secondary").css({"margin-left":"0", "transition":"1s"});
   });
  }
 e.stopPropagation();
}

function doYourStuffforMouseLeaveEvent(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
     var Item = e.target.id;
     alert("This item is the current hover item " + Item );
     $(".primary").css({"margin-right":"30px", "transition":"1s"});
     $(".secondary").css({"margin-left":"30px", "transition":"1s"});
    });
  }
 e.stopPropagation();
}
```